# nodejs install issue in linux

Tags: node.js, gunicorn

```
     sudo apt-get install nodejs
[sudo] password for akhil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-51 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
  ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 140 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-gunicorn (19.4.5-1ubuntu1) ...
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/gunicorn
dpkg: error processing package python-gunicorn (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gunicorn:
 gunicorn depends on python-gunicorn (= 19.4.5-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package python-gunicorn is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gunicorn (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-gunicorn
 gunicorn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am trying to install nodejs on my system.But the above error occured.
I already installed gunicorn in my system.Please figureout what is the real issue?

Comment: Did u run the commands described here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Comment: Oh and also, seems that u have nodejs installed already: `nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.1).`

Comment: try running `node -v`

Comment: i need to install dalekjs.But this error occuring

Comment: Did `node -v` return anything? If yes then you should run `npm install dalek-cli -g`